# WCF , soap 1.1 replace prefix

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap

WCF framework, I want to change the response format from s:envelope to soap:envelop, here is the solution (url link):

blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/06/13/changing-prefixes-in-xml-responses.aspx

however ,the code support soap 1.2, my requirement is to support soap 1.1 ,which not work properly .  I changed the code below : 
from (WSHttpBinding)

```
Dictionary<string, string> namespaceToPrefixMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
{

    { "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", "SOAP12-ENV" },
    { "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "SOAP12-ADDR" },
};
```

to (BasicHttpBinding)

```
Dictionary<string, string> namespaceToPrefixMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
{

    { "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "soap" },
    { "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "soap" },
};
```

so the client will response with message below:

The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

How should I continue with my code ?

Comment: It should not be necessary to change the prefix. The prefix should not matter to any client that understands XML. The prefix is not important - only the _namespace_ represented by the prefix is important. If your client requires a particular prefix, then it is very badly broken and should be ashamed of itself.

Comment: But the requirement is that prefix, I also don't want to change the prefix

Comment: Then you have either misunderstood the requirement, or your client misunderstands XML.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on this article:

http://vanacosmin.ro/Articles/Read/WCFEnvelopeNamespacePrefix.

The approach is different from the one you have, because here the transformation takes place before the Message is sent to the channels. It uses MessageFormatter instead of MessageEncoder. Changing the message with the MessageFormatter will let you use the changed version in the other layers (e.g. for logging) and will also not have problems if you're required later to add message security.